# Problem with reading last line of code algorithm - c++

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I found this code on Stackoverflow:

```
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg(-1, std::ios_base::end);
        if (file.peek() == '\n')
        {
            //Start searching for \n occurrences
            file.seekg(-1, std::ios_base::cur);
            int i = file.tellg();
            for (i;i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (file.peek() == '\n')
                {
                    //Found
                    file.get();
                    break;
                }
                //Move one character back
                file.seekg(i, std::ios_base::beg);
            }
                string line;
                getline(file,line);
        }
```

It saves the last line of file in variable 'line', and it works ok, but if the last line is the first line it doesn't read the first character of line (the rest is read). When the last line is eg.the third line everything works. What's the problem?

Comment: Don't mess with code you don't understand. Try to understand the code first and ask for help with that if you need to.

Comment: What is the return value of `getline(file,line);`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all of your code only runs when the last character is `'\n'`.

If that is not so, then your program does nothing.

You need to rethink the `if (file.peek() == '\n')` part.

Comment: I have no idea how to change it, honestly

Comment: I'd like to remind it only doesn't read the first character of a line, the rest is ok

Comment: Let me go out with an example:
if I a have file:
` Monica Smith `
it saves only "onica Smith"

Answer (score 0):

Here follows a solution. It uses another method that requires the whole file to be read into a string. But it seems to solve your issue.
This function will return the last line of a text file.

```
std::string get_last_line(const std::string& s_file_name)
{
    std::ifstream file(s_file_name);

    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    std::size_t p = str.find_last_of("\n");

    if (p != std::string::npos)
        return str.substr(p+1, str.length() - p);

    return str;
}
```

Although it uses more memory, I believe this code will run faster since it does not require several calls to the OS file system.

Answer (score 0):

There are several conditions that you need to take into account when backing up looking for the last line in a text file.

1. you don't care what the last character in the file is. The file may (or may not) have a POSIX *end-of-file* (a `'\n'` as the final character of the last line),
2. what is relevant is that after seeking the end of file, you are not also at the beginning (empty-file); then you can
3. start looping looking for the `'\n'` before the last line in the file (keep a counter of the offset from the end and when the offset isn't one-before the end and `file.peek() == '\n'`, then break the loop; and finally
4. check you are not at the beginning or if the 1<sup>st</sup> char is `'\n'`, if so, advance the file position by one, and
5. read the last line.

You can code the logic several different ways, but if you are doing this in a function, you are either going to pass a reference to an open `std::ifstream` or pass the filename to open within the function. If you pass a reference to the open file-stream, you want your function return type to be the same reference to the open file-stream so the *stream state* can be validated to detect a stream error. (you will also check `string.length() != 0` on return to ensure the file wasn't empty)

Putting that altogether, you could write a get last line file using your file operations similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::ifstream& getlastline (std::ifstream& f, std::string& last)
{
    long offsetend = 0;     /* initial offset from end */

    /* if file not empty */
    if (f.seekg(offsetend, std::ios_base::end) && f.tellg())
        /* loop continually seeking 1 before current offsetend */
        while (f.seekg(offsetend - 1, std::ios_base::end)) {
            /* if at beginning or offsetend and '\n' */
            if (!f.tellg() || (offsetend < 0 && f.peek() == '\n'))
                break;
            offsetend--;        /* decrement offsetend */
        }
    /* if not at beginning, or 1st char is '\n' advance by 1 */
    if (f.tellg() || f.peek() == '\n')
        f.seekg(offsetend, std::ios_base::end);

    if (!getline (f, last)) /* read last line */
        std::cerr << "error: getline() read of last line.\n";

    return f;       /* return stream state */
}
```

Adding a short example that allows you to provide the filename to read as the first argument to the program, you could do:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "error: filename required as 1st argument.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string last {};
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);

    if (!getlastline (f, last) || last.length() == 0) {
        std::cerr << "error: stream error or file was empty.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << last << '\n';
}
```

By approaching it this way, you will get the last line regardless of whether there is a POSIX end-of-file contained in the file, and it will also handle the empty-file case as well.

Of course if all the files you are dealing with are a few hundred lines or less, you can do away with the offset from the end entirely and simply read all lines saving the last -- it makes a dramatic simplification, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "error: filename required as 1st argument.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string current {}, last {};
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);

    while (getline (f, current))
        last = current;

    /* (add any length validations here) */
    std::cout << last << '\n';
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.